# Python yfinance - Getting E-Mini S&P 500 Futures term structures on a given date

Tags: python, yfinance

I am just a beginner of python and now I am coding to get the plot graph of E-Mini S&P 500 Futures term structure on a given date. After searching several sources, I have got the code and executed it, but the result seems different from my expectation.

The code I applied is as the below:

```
import pandas as pd
#!pip install yfinance
import yfinance as yf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


tickerlist = ["ESU23.CME","ESZ23.CME", "ESH24.CME", "ESM24.CME", "ESU24.CME", "ESZ24.CME" ]

def download(symbol):
    opt = yf.download(symbol, period = 'max')
    opt["Ticker"] = symbol
    
    return opt
    

data = pd.DataFrame()


for ticker in tickerlist:
    data = data.append(download(ticker))
        
data = data.drop_duplicates()         

data.info()
data = data.reset_index() 
data.info()      
data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])

data['maturity'] = data['Ticker'].apply(lambda x : x.replace('ESU23.CME','2023/9')\
                                         .replace('ESZ23.CME', '2023/12')\
                                         .replace('ESH24.CME', '2024/3')\
                                         .replace('ESM24.CME', '2024/6')\
                                         .replace('ESU24.CME', '2024/9')\
                                         .replace('ESZ24.CME', '2024/12'))


data1 = data[data['Date'] == pd.to_datetime('2023-09-13')]  
    

# Figure 1
plt.xlabel("Maturity")
plt.ylabel("Close")
plt.title("Figure 1 ES as of 9/13/2022")
plt.plot(data1['maturity'], data1['Close'], marker = "o", color = "royalblue")
plt.show()
```

The result of this code is as the following image:
[graph image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPYEr.png)

Now, here is my question.

1. What is the interpretation of each line in the code? I know some of the functions, but still not fully understand the overall flow of this code. Even rough explanation would be appreciated.
2. Why does the graph show only three spots (2023/9, 2023/12, 2024/3) and miss the others (2024/6, 2024/9, 24/12)?

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.